# webpack-dev-server not working from debugger on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an issue with getting webpack-dev-server to run from the debugger in Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. The project runs perfectly on Linux and Mac, but for some reason it errors out on windows. It also works fine from VSC's tasks implementation, and from the command line on *all platforms*. Thank you in advance for your help.

Please note I have posted this issue in two other places in case this is a bug:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/785
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20350

The error I get on windows is the following:

> Cannot launch program 'c:\devel\src\MyWebKit\node_modules.bin\webpack-dev-server'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.

My current setup is:

> VSC: 1.9.1
>
> OS: Windows 10 Anniversary
>
> webpack: 2.2.1
>
> webpack-dev-server: 2.3.0

My configuration launch.json file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
        "args": [
            "-d",
            "--config",
            "webpack/default.js"
        ],
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/build/*"
        ],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to debug the webpack-dev-server instance or the application that is served by the devserver?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I want to debug the application that is served out of the dev server, like I am able to do beautifully under Mac/linux with this setup.

Comment: In this case please take a look at my sample application https://github.com/skolmer/react-hot-boilerplate-vscode It uses a tasks.json configuration to start the dev server and a launch.json config to debug the running web app with vscode chrome debugger. hope this helps.